# Redirecting a public subdomain to a local ip

Tags: networking, dns, ip, redirection, localhost

So I've been working on a little project at home with a Raspberry Pi. I wanted to set up some kind of intranet for my household to use, and everything's been working fine, but I found that using an ip every time is a bit boring.
So I decided to see if I could redirect a subdomain from one of my public domains to my local ip. I added the A record yesterday, and it seems like it only works on my Android phone right now. All the iOS tablets and Windows PCs in the house don't seem to be able to reach the local ip when I access the subdomain (although typing the ip manually does work).
Does anyone know what could be causing this? I thought it could be because I was using the Google DNS on my phone, but after disabling it there's no problem either... So I'm kinda lost!
Sorry for my noobish question, networking usually isn't my thing and this is my first "local network" kind of project.

Thanks!

Comment: Look into router hairpinning. That's the way to 'see inside, from inside'.

Comment: Are all the devices on the same Wifi network?

Comment: They are on the same network, yes. I can access the Pi with my PC by typing the IP address directly.